# How can I find "real user" accounts with empty password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

hoping to expand the question asked [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/240957/how-find-user-with-empty-password-in-linux), about finding users with empty passwords. What I want is filter out the system accounts that the line

```
sudo getent shadow | grep '^[^:]*:.\?:' | cut -d: -f1
```

prints out when I run it.

My problem is that I want to be able to display only the users accounts with empty passwords that were added by script or via terminal in my system, a.k.a. the "real" people, as well as the accounts that I've made myself.

## **In depth:**

What happens *now*:

```
~$ sudo useradd bob

~$ sudo getent shadow | grep '^[^:]*:.\?:' | cut -d: -f1
Sudo password for user: [pw]
daemon
bin
sys
[...]
rtkit
saned
usbmux
bob
~$
```

What is *desired*:

```
~$ sudo useradd bob

~$ sudo [getent command for the problem]
Sudo password for user: [pw]
bob
~$
```

In other words, when I add Bob without a password, I want to be able to see only him.

This is probably *not* well worded so please ask for further clarification.

The use for this is to find all users with the mentioned properties and delete them. Thus, I don't want to delete system-created accounts.

---

**Update 1:** Corrected typos.

---

**Update 2:** I have found that I can filter out all users by their ID, which is the third field received by `getent`.

Thus, running 2 grep though a pipeline, like this:

```
sudo getent shadow | grep '^[^:]*:.\?:' | grep (regex) | cut -d: -f1
```

will get the job done.

Now, the regular expression I understand that I should use is `'.:.:[^(17212)]:.:.:.:.:.:.'`, but it just doesn't bring back any matches.

Can someone suggest any alternatives?

---

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you for your help.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Case Solved:**

Using the following:

```
sudo getent shadow |  awk  -F ':' '{print $1 \" \"$2 \" \" $3}
```

in combination with a custom parser in the script has enabled me to get all user accounts with empty password in a list inside the application.

Then, with the 17212 property, I can tell apart system accounts from user accounts.

Be warned, this way of telling system accounts from user accounts may not work for you. (credit  to @MirMasej in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

User account ids start from 1000, lower ids belong to system accounts, so you need to filter those out - id is the third field of the output of

```
> getent passwd
```

Comment: I took the cut command off to see all the fields - the system accouts have the id 17212, whereas "Bob" has 17247. Is the "1000" restriction right, or should I only restrict, in my case, 17212 and lower?

Comment: The set of numeric user ids allocated to user vs. system accounts can vary from one system to another.

Comment: @KeithThompson I do realize that this is by convention, but I cannot recall a case when it wouldn't have been kept. Apparently that's the case here.

Comment: @ThemistoklisGkasios what is the user with id 17212? I don't think, that in this case it's a "border" id (like 1000 in a typical set up), rather some service to be set up that way. Another field you could try is a shell (the last one from passwd) - services have *usually* set this as either /usr/bin/nologin or /bin/false. I admit that my system has PostgreSQL with /bin/bash though so for me combination of that two would work. Regarding your second update: `getent shadow` doesn't show any user ids for me. Side note: you can use `grep -v` to filter out something.

Comment: My solution to the problem was to use `sudo getent shadow |  awk  -F ':' '{print $1 \" \"$2 \" \" $3}`, and parse the result with a custom parser in the application itself

Comment: I then filtered out the system accounts using the `ID!=17212` property, and that solves my problem.

I then use the filtered content for a empty-password-user mass deletion, using `"sudo userdel "+userid` for each user detected.